# Controller using ASP.NET Core 6 with NLog appears not to get the correct logger instance via DI

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0, nlog

Having an issue getting the correct logger via DI, at least that is what it seems.

Here is the code in Program.cs:

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info("Service Init");
logger.Info($"  Log Level - Debug: {logger.IsEnabled(NLog.LogLevel.Debug)} Trace: {logger.IsEnabled(NLog.LogLevel.Trace)}");

try
{
  var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

  builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
  //builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
  builder.Host.UseNLog();

  builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

  var app = builder.Build();

  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseRouting();

  app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

  app.Run();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
  // NLog: catch setup errors
  logger.Error(exc, "Stopped program because of exception");
  throw;
}
finally
{
  NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

When I run the app the initial log information (logged to file) shows the correct values for the log level, for example if I set minlog in NLog.config to "Debug" then the value shows true in the log and similarly if I change it to "Trace" the log shows appropriately.

In a controller when I try and log the same information using the below, they are always false:

```
  _logger.Info($"Log Level - Debug: {_logger.IsEnabled(NLog.LogLevel.Debug)} Trace: {_logger.IsEnabled(NLog.LogLevel.Trace)}");
```

**Additional notes:**

- In the controller, any controller, no logs are being written to the configured log file. Only thing making it to the configured log file is from the logger instance created in Program.cs.
- I have a number of other solutions using the prior generation setup where you have Program.cs and Startup.cs. Those solutions also use CreateHostBuilder(args).Build() instead of WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args). The prior generation setup works as expected.
- NLog.Exensions.Logging and NLog.Web.AspNetCore versions are both 5.2.1
- Home Controller

```
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

**And more notes:**
I commented out the logger in Program.cs and also made use of this to obtain the configuration from appsettings.config. I've also made use of this when I create the instance of logger in Program.cs and so I know the configuration is correct:

- builder.Host.UseNLog(new NLogAspNetCoreOptions() { LoggingConfigurationSectionName = "NLog" });

Regardless of creating logger instance in Program.cs, when I do a QuickWatch of the logger instance passed into a controller constructor I see the the below. The provider type looks good, NLog, but where it is picking up a configuration I'm at a loss.

[image: QuickWatch of logger instance in controller]

Finally, as per a suggestion from Rolf, I add this in Program.cs to see what NLog was doing, unfortunately it didn't given much detail. No configuration information listed:

```
  NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogLevel = NLog.LogLevel.Trace;
  NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;
  NLog.Common.InternalLogger.LogFile = @"c:\temp\nlog-debug.txt";
```

The log output looks like this:

```
2023-01-08 08:58:50.5328 Debug ScanAssembly('NLog, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c')
2023-01-08 08:58:50.6446 Debug ScanAssembly('NLog.Web.AspNetCore, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c')
2023-01-08 08:58:50.6610 Trace Assembly 'NLog.Web.AspNetCore, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' will be hidden in callsite stacktrace
2023-01-08 08:58:50.9908 Debug Hide assemblies for callsite
2023-01-08 08:58:50.9914 Debug ScanAssembly('NLog.Extensions.Logging, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c')
2023-01-08 08:58:50.9914 Trace Assembly 'NLog.Extensions.Logging, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' will be hidden in callsite stacktrace
2023-01-08 08:58:50.9914 Trace Assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' will be hidden in callsite stacktrace
2023-01-08 08:58:50.9914 Trace Assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' will be hidden in callsite stacktrace
2023-01-08 08:58:51.0219 Trace ParseNLogConfig
```

Comment: Maybe enable the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging) at Debug-Level to follow what `NLog.config`-file is being used, and what loglevels are enabled for the individual NLog Loggers. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: Curious that you say Dependency Injection (DI), but from your controller-code-example then it looks like a NLog Logger, and not the expected Microsoft ILogger resolved as constructor-input-parameters. Can the question be updated to include the source-code for the Controller-constructor? Maybe also include the NLog.config ?

Comment: What version of NLog are you using ? It is recommended to use latest NLog.Web.AspNetCore v5 as it ensures that it is only Logging-Rules in NLog.config that applies (Ignores default filtering applied by Microsoft LoggerFactory).

Answer (score 2):

So I feel like I should delete this post to keep people from chasing down the wrong path ;)

Nevertheless, the solution was simple, and a very dumb mistake on my part. In nlog.config I had something like this:

```
  <logger name="<MyNameSpace>.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />
```

...where `<MyNameSpace>` is simply that, the namespace of the project.

I had something similar in another solution but it was less aggressive `<MyNameSpace>.<SubNameSpace>`.

Basically I was eliminating from the logs junk I didn't want, but I went to far.

Anyway, lesson is be careful with your rule because you will take the "applicable logger" out of the equation leaving you wondering why your logger isn't looking like or performing like you think it should.